# How do I demonstrate Jordan measurability of a compact convex polytope?

Tags: measure-theory, polytopes

Ex 1.1.9 in Tao's *An introduction to measure theory* asks us to show that any compact convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is Jordan measurable. Is the following an efficient (or even valid) approach to the problem?

1. Show that every $d$-dimensional solid simplex is Jordan measurable; and
2. Show that any compact convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be expressed as a union of disjoint $d$-dimensional solid simplices.

Comment: Handling part 2 properly may be more convoluted than the full direct aproach

Comment: Answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3688947/52454

Answer (score 0):

This follows from Exercise 1.1.7.

It's easier to see this in $d=3$. But higher dimension should work.

In 3-space, we project the polytope to the $xy$ plane. This gives a convex polygon. We can enclose this in a box $B$ and view the original polytope as the space between two continuous function $f_1$ and $f_2$ on the domain $B$. Then follows from 1.1.7 that the space between $B$ and $f_1$ is measurable, and the space between $B$ and $f_2$ is also measurable. So the original polytope is also measurable.

Answer (score -1):

I think this could work:

A convex polytope can be parameterized as the solution set of half spaces
$$a_{i1}x_1+...+a_{in}x_n\le b_i
$$
or equivalently $Ax\le b$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ and $b$ an $m \times 1$ matrix.
As $B\subset \mathbb{R} $ is compact, each half space $H_i=\sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{ij}x_j$ is bounded and Jordan measurable. Additionally, as seen in Exercise 6, the intersection $H_1\cap...\cap H_m$ is again Jordan measurable.

Comment: I do not see how exactly does Jordan measurability follow from boundedness. Could you elaborate more?